# Laravel rest api authentication

Tags: rest, laravel, authentication, curl

I am a beginner with building a rest api and authentication.
I've just been reading the following and explains a very simple setup:

[laravel 5 rest api basic authentication](https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-rest-api-basic-authentication/)

At the bottom the article explains not to send usernames and password with headers or in the url.

My question is basicly: can anyone give me an example how to use a cUrl request with the example above?

For example:

```
$service_url = 'http://example.com/api/conversations';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = array(
        'user' => 'user@user.com',
        'passw' => '1234'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/support/remote-auth use this package its a very amazing and easy to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel is shipped with Guzzle – an advanced HTTP client library. It's probably more reasonable to use that than a low-level cURL.

To do basic auth with Guzzle:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post('http://example.com/api/conversations', [
    'auth' => [
        'user@user.com', 
        '1234'
    ]
]);
```

The response will be in $response->getBody();

If your target endpoint uses SSL – it's not too bad sending the credentials in the headers, but the trendy way is to use temporary tokens (eg. API key or OAuth access token).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, you can also create a generic function to handle all your curl requests.

You can use the following function to call external webservices and return the data/authentication information.

```
/*=============================================
  * Call External Webservices using CURL
  *
  * @param $requestURL, $header -> (OPTIONAL)
  * @return json
  #=============================================*/
  public function curlRequest($requestURL, $headers = array())
  {
    $getData = curl_init($requestURL);
    curl_setopt($getData, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($getData, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($getData, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    if (count($headers) != 0) {
      curl_setopt($getData, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }
    $response = curl_exec($getData);
    return json_decode($response);
  }
```

Use case specific example to use the above function for authentication:

```
$requestURL = 'http://www.example.com/api/userLogin';
$userAuthInfo = [
    'email'=> 'example@example.com', 
    'password'=>'123456'
 ];
$result = $this->curlRequest($requestURL, $userAuthInfo);
dd($result); //Print the Result of the Authentication request
```